# How to exclude a directory from a dir call loop--faster than |find /v

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, find, batch-processing, dir

Right now I've got a batch script that is used to go through a bunch of subfolders, and zip up the logfiles therein, the folder structure is basically like this:

```
+---fakeG
|   +---ExclusionFolder
|   |   +---LimitlessFolders
|   |   +---MoreFolders
|   |   \---SoManyFolders
|   +---logs1
|   +---logs2
|   +---logs3
|   +---logs4
|   +---logs5
|   \---logs6
```

Each of these subfolders must be traversed, and their subfolders traversed as well. This script has to avoid one specific folder, and it does avoid it, but it uses %| find /v. Although in this example, ExclusionFolder is at the top of the list, in the real folder structure it is not.

Here is how I do it now:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (
    'DIR "%LogsFilespec%" /B /S ^| find /v "ExclusionFolder"'
) DO CALL :DoZip "%%~dpnA" "%%~fA" "%zipCommand%" "%zipParams%" %ProcessLog%
```

Inside ExclusionFolder, there are more subfolders, with potentially many more subfolders, so it would slow down the scripts execution having to go into each of them.

**SO: Is there a faster way to exclude a folder from a dir call without |find ?**

Or do I have to come up with a totally different way to do this?

**Edit** Sorry, %LogsFileSpec℅ refers to the target file. My original edit was right, and my second edit was wrong.

```
SET LogsLocation="G:\fakeG\Data\Logs"
SET LogsName="trace*%targetDate%.log"
SET LogsFilespec="%LogsLocation%\%LogsName%"
```

Sorry for not giving more of the script, I figured the question didn't need much.

**Edit2** The process :DoZip works like this:

```
:DoZip
:: Parameter 1 = Filename without .EXT for Archive Name
:: Parameter 2 = Target file specifics
:: Parameter 3 = Zip Command (Winzip/7zip64/7zip32)
:: Parameter 4 = Zip Parameters (a -tzip, -a)
:: Parameter 5 = ProcessLog
setlocal 
SET archiveName=%~1
SET SourceFileSpec=%~2
SET zipCommand=%~3
SET zipParms=%~4
SET RunLog=%~5

    ECHO %TIME% Archiving %SourceFileSpec%...
    ECHO %TIME% Archiving %SourceFileSpec%... >> %RunLog%

    ECHO "%zipCommand%" %zipParms% "%archiveName%.zip" "%SourceFileSpec%"
    ECHO "%zipCommand%" %zipParms% "%archiveName%.zip" "%SourceFileSpec%" >> %RunLog%
    "%zipCommand%" %zipParms% "%archiveName%.zip" "%SourceFileSpec%" >> %RunLog%

 :: Check errorlevel of executed command
 :: If errorlevel != 0, set EC with the errorlevel and echo that there was an error in archival
 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    ECHO ***ERROR archiving %SourceFileSpec% >>                                                                         %RunLog%
    SET EC=%ERRORLEVEL%
    ECHO ***ERRORLEVEL RETURNED: %EC% >> %RunLog%
) ELSE (
 :: Otherwise, delete the file
    ECHO. >>                                                                                                                            %RunLog%
    ECHO. >>                                                                                                                            %RunLog%
    ECHO %TIME% Deleting %SourceFileSpec%...
    ECHO %TIME% Deleting %SourceFileSpec%... >>                                                                         %RunLog%
 ::Quietly delete the file
    DEL /Q %SourceFileSpec%

    :: Set ErrorLevel to capture the Delete command result.
    SET EC=%ERRORLEVEL%
)
GOTO :EOF
```

**Edit 3** Here is zipCommand

```
SET PathWinZip=C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzzip.exe
SET Path7Zip_64bit=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
SET Path7Zip_32bit=C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe

:: Check for WinZip
IF EXIST "%PathWinZip%" SET zipCommand=%PathWinZip% & SET zipParms=-a 

:: Check for 32-bit version of 7-Zip. If found, configure
:: its command line parameter to produce a .zip file
IF EXIST "%Path7Zip_32bit%" SET zipCommand=%Path7Zip_32bit% & SET zipParms=a -tzip

:: Check for 64-bit version of 7-Zip. If found, configure
:: its command line parameter to produce a .zip file
IF EXIST "%Path7Zip_64bit%" SET zipCommand=%Path7Zip_64bit% & SET zipParms=a -tzip
```

Comment: Can you specify the other files with a more specific expression than `%LogsFilespec%`? For example, based upon what you show, it could be, `FOR /F ... IN ( 'DIR %LogsFilesspec%/logs*' /B /S'...) ...` or something like that...

Comment: Don't knowing `:DoZip` procedure: some _zipping_ tools, maybe most of them, allow use of a _file list_ or some kind of quasi script. Might be faster to create such list (a set of particular lists) and call adapted `:DoZipList`?

Comment: Please show the definition of all variables and show the `:DoZip` routine,  and/or better describe what you are trying to do. There very well may be a better way to accomplish your task, but you haven't provided enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the following should exclude the subtree in question:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%X IN (
    'DIR /B /ad ') DO IF /i "%%X" neq "ExclusionFolder" FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (
    'DIR  /B /S "%%X\%LogsFilespec%"'
) DO CALL :DoZip "%%~dpnA" "%%~fA" "%zipCommand%" "%zipParams%" %ProcessLog%
```

That is, perform a directory-name scan of the target; if the directory found is not the exclude-name, then do the remainder for that subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm trying this solution, but getting     `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Tried CD'ing to the directory before the loop, just output more of these.

Comment: I realized I had a typo in my CD. Now, its finding all the log files including the ones it shouldn't be archiving, BUT it does ignore ExclusionFolder! But it's not actually archiving or deleting them, its just echoing to cmd the text it's supposed to be appending to %RunLog% inside DoZip...

Comment: In that case, the problem would have to be in `DOZIP`. You appear to say that the parameters being supplied are as you expect them to be, so that problem appears unrelated to your "exclude directory" problem. As you haven't published what `zipCommand` is, I suspect it must be a batch file, so `dozip` will transfer control to that batch file and the remainder after `"%zipCommand%"...` will be skipped. Try `call "%zipCommand%"...` to provide `dozip` with a return location.

Comment: Sorry, zipCommand is just a variable being set earlier in the script. I edited my original post for clarification. I'm worried now that a problem I faced previously with this document has resurfaced, which is the intricacies of quotation marks messing with the zip command lines.... Edit: Yes, its as I suspected: The correct commandline would appear as such: `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe " a -tzip "C:\Users\me\Documents\fakeG\logs2\trace_20150217.zip" "C:\Users\me\Documents\fakeG\logs2\trace_20150217.log" ` but instead `a -tzip` is being excluded in the output now.

Comment: Oh my! I realized that `zipParms` wasnt working because you rewrote my DoZip call with `zipParams` like a regular human being, whereas mine was originally `zipParms`!! Onto the final piece of the puzzle, this script now archives every log, not just the ones adhering to `trace*%targetDate%.log`

Comment: Ahhh it was because my LogsFileSpec variable was being set with the parent-folder like so LogsFileSpec = %LogsFileFolder%\%LogsFileName%! Your code works now, the transplant was successful! Thanks Magoo!

Answer (score 1):

This approach could be a bit faster:

```
pushd "%LogsFilespec%"
rem get subfolders of first level only
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in (
  'DIR "%LogsFilespec%" /B /AD ^| find /v "ExclusionFolder"'
  ) do (  
    rem treat each (here will not be excluded one) 
    FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (
      'DIR "%%~p" /B /S'
    ) DO CALL :DoZip "%%~dpnA" "%%~fA" "%zipCommand%" "%zipParams%" %ProcessLog%
)
popd
goto :eof
```